# Unable to install libpq-dev in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dependencies

I am try to install `libpq-dev` in ubuntu 16.04 and it come with this problem:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I try to install `krb5-multidev` by using command `sudo apt-get install krb5-multidev` but i got this error :

```
krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed        
Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed                 
Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It look like that it got conflict with the ubuntu package
So can anyone help me to solve this problem please !!!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy krb5-multidev`.

Comment: thanks for the link the command sudo aptitude help me lower the version thus allow me to install krb5-multidev and then the libpq-dev package

Answer (score -1):

Please try these commands, starting with cleaning the temp files, configure all unpacked but un-configured packages, then fix broken package dependencies, update, and install libpq:

```
sudo apt-get clean   
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get -f install  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I great you, none of these commands would seem to be relevent to the question, and the commands are all things that should not typically help, but reasons I don't understand, these worked for me! Huh!